# Deploying C# database application with SQL server gives Null Object reference error after installation. Deploying the database on Client PC

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database

I have developed an application in C#.NET using SQL SERVER LocalDB 2012. Now application runs fine on pressing F5 (means in visual studio development environment) . But when I try to install this application on my local PC or in Vmware machine, it gives Null Object reference error as

> > object reference not set to an instance of an object
> >     See the end of this message for details on invoking 
> >     just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.
> >
> > ************** Exception Text **************
> >     System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an >object.    at
> >     intermediateProject.main.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)    at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()    at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
> >     at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()    at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)    at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)    at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)    at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)    at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)    at
> >     System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
> >     at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
> >     m)    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32
> >     msg, IntPtr             wparam, IntPtr lparam)
> >
> > ************* Loaded Assemblies ************** mscorlib
> >         Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
> >         Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
> >         CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
> >     --------------------------------------- Agri Foods
> >         Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
> >         Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
> >         CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/cokeStudio/My%20Product%20Name/Agri%20Foods.exe
> >     --------------------------------------- System.Windows.Forms
> >         Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
> >         Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34250 built by: FX452RTMGDR
> >         CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
> >     -------------------------------------- System.Drawing
> >         Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
> >         Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.36337 built by: FX452RTMLDR
> >         CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
> >     ----------------------------------- System
> >         Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
> >         Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34239 built by: FX452RTMGDR
> >         CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
> >     --------------------------------------- System.Configuration
> >         Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
> >         Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
> >         CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0>0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
> >     --------------------------------------- System.Xml
> >         Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
> >         Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34281 built by: FX452RTMGDR
> >         CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
> >     --------------------------------------- System.Data
> >         Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
> >         Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
> >         CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
> >     --------------------------------------- System.Core
> >         Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
> >         Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
> >         CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
> >     --------------------------------------- System.Data.DataSetExtensions
> >         Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
> >         Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL
> >         CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Data.DataSetExtensions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll
> >     --------------------------------------- System.Numerics
> >         Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
> >         Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
> >         CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Numerics/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Numerics.dll
> >     --------------------------------------- Accessibility
> >         Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0
> >         Win32 Version: 4.0.30319.33440 built by: FX45W81RTMREL
> >
> > ### CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Accessibility/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll
> >
> > ************* JIT Debugging ************** To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this application or computer
> >     (machine.config) must have the jitDebugging value set in the
> >     system.windows.forms section. The application must also be compiled
> >     with debugging enabled.
> >
> > For example:
> >
> > When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer rather than be handled
> >     by this dialog box.
> >
> > object reference not set to an instance of an object....
>
> I have tried to add Database Project also but could not find it use
>   full .
>
> [1]:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9cjq.png

I am using the connection string as follows:

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress;       Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

     </connectionStrings>
```

And Also the form load code is as follows:

```
     private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString);

         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from fianlTable", con);
         sda.Fill(dt);
         dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

       }
```

Comment: Can you post your code in the Form1_Load?

Comment: Dr. Stitch Plz review the code as I have added my connection string and also I have edited my database to SQLEXPRESS. I am having trouble when I make setup installer . When I run the code it runs fine on Visual Studio runtime. You can see Form1_Load code with reference to connection string. Thanks – Muhammad Shahid